# How do I get Uncrustify to indent dot continuation lines?

Tags: uncrustify

How can I configure [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) to format this:

```
entity.Property(e => e.CaseId)
.HasColumnName("CaseID")
.HasMaxLength(20);
```

like this:

```
entity.Property(e => e.CaseId)
    .HasColumnName("CaseID")
    .HasMaxLength(20);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This setting got the result:

```
# The number of spaces to indent a continued '->' or '.'
# Usually set to 0, 1, or indent_columns.
indent_member                   = 8        # number
```